# Android. Is there an intent to go to the default Apps page?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser, android-dialer, telecom-manager

I have this code to set my app as the default dialer:

```
 val telecomManager = getSystemService(TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
        val isAlreadyDefaultDialer = packageName == telecomManager.defaultDialerPackage
        if (isAlreadyDefaultDialer) return

        val intent = Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
                .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER)
```

Which works fine. And it's set on a checkbox. But I want when the user unchecks it, to make an intent to show me the "Default Apps" page. Or if not to fallback to the default android dialer. Is that possible?

I tried:

```
val intent = Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER)
                .putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.android.phone")
```

But it doesn't do anything. 
Also "ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS" but that goes tot he apps page. I want to go to the default apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this that works for me:

```
    var i = Intent(ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS)
        startActivity(i)
```